# Probability to find $k$ distinct prime factors lower than $B$

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

We are given a number $n$ and an arbitrary bound $B$. What is the probability that $n$ has $k$ distinct prime factors lower than $B$?

Let us put it another way. We are given the sequence of the $l$ first prime numbers. What is the probability that $n$ has exactly $k$ distinct prime factors in this sequence?